# migrate php site from http to https

Tags: php, http, https, migration

i read the other threads about this topic but i couldn't find anything that i felt could apply in my case. It seams pretty basic though. I have a website built in php with apache server. In this moment all the traffic is done via http. The people who paid for the site, now want to move it to https. They bought a certificate and the web server hosts will install it. What changes do i need to make to make it work via https, besides changing the redirects within the code?
I also found this link which seems pretty helpful, but i think maybe it's too complex?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your resource links (like external JavaScript references such as jQuery) in the site where there are hard-coded paths in http://domain.name/some-link-here to just //domain.name/some-link-here. This will prevent the browser from complaining about mixed-mode content.

For links that are on the same domain, you could use absolute/relative URLs.

After that you can place and .htaccess such that any URLs accessed on the domain would automatically redirect to the HTTPS version. Place the following lines as the first rule in the file

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The .htaccess will also take care of any hard-coded links (towards the same domain/site) that you might have in your site and that you have missed.

Comment: Thanks. And on the apache server there is nothing thats needs to be done? Like something stated [here](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/)

Comment: You mentioned "They bought a certificate and the web server hosts will install it.", therefore you don't have any server side configuration to make yourself as the server administrators will take care of that.

Comment: Yes i thought so too. But they also said there won't be any downtime and i thought that maybe that means that they won do the server side config. Should there be a downtime if they also configure the server?

Comment: You should not assume these things. Better ask them directly. The server can be configured without shutting it down and after the configuration Apache can be restarted quite quickly and the downtime will not be noticeable. You also don't mention what type of hosting it is (shared, dedicated, etc), whether you have full control for accessing the server or if configuration is made via a web control panel...

Comment: Yes, i should find out these things. The ommunication between me and the server admin is filtered by a very nontechnical person, to say the least:). It is a shared server and i have access to a web control pannel

Comment: @user3195199, you should update your question and add the required details. Asking further questions in the comments about the SSL certificate setup is not recommended and will not generate an answer. You should either accept the answer that pertains to your original question if it solved your original issue or update the question to make it clear what the problem actually is.